# Spring's Entity inside nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, spring, redis

The way I manage persistent state inside my backends in the past is by using Spring's `@Entity`. Basically, I define a regular java class like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public Long user_id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String email;
}
```

Then I can use Hibernate to retrieve a managed java object:

```java
User user = userFactory.getUserFromId(3L); // uses Hibernate internally to get a managed instance
user.email = "abc@company.com"; // gets auto-save to mysql database
```

This is highly convenient, as I can just change the fields without explicitly worrying about saving data. It's also quite convenient as I can specify a number of fields to be used as an index, so I can search for matching email names quite fast.

How would I go about doing the same thing using NodeJS? I need to use node as my team is not familiar with Java at all. I want to be able to store complex json objects fast, have a cached version in memory that ideally stores data permanently at regular intervals.

My current plan is to use Redis for this. Getting user's object should look something like this:

```js
class User {
    constructor(json) {
        this.json = json
    }

    async save() {
        await redis.set(JSON.stringify(this.json));
    }
}

async function user(id) {
    let json = JSON.parse(await redis.get("user-" + id));
    return User(json);
}

u3 = await user(3);
u3.json.email = "def@company.com";
u3.save();
```

To get user by name, I'd create my own index (mapping from email to user id), and potentially store this index inside redis as well.

All of this seems clunky, and feels like I'm reimplementing basic database features. So before I do it like this, are there different ways to manage json objects well in js, so that the coding experience is somewhat the same as in Spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping), that is that tool in every language that maps your objects into database records.

With a quick search you can find [Sequalize](https://sequelize.org/) that is very popular in the NodeJS world.

Comment: Another option is TypeORM.